# When did these characters elude Bane in The Dark Knight Rises?

Tags: dc, batman, nolan-batman-trilogy, the-dark-knight-rises

In *The Dark Knight Rises*, Bane

> takes the Wayne Enterprises board hostage, and “forces” Lucius Fox and Miranda Tate to give him access to the nuclear thingy.

This hostage-taking is what prompts

> the police to head into the sewers, where they are promptly trapped when Bane sets off his explosives and takes control of Gotham.

Some time later

> a special forces team covertly enters the city, and are taken by Jim Gordon and John Blake to meet Lucius and Miranda, who are living in a building which is then raided by Bane & his soldiers, who re-capture Fox and Miranda.

But when did these characters get free from Bane in the first place? Did he just let them wander off at some point? Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, a big plot point in this film is that

> Miranda Tate is actually Talia al Ghul, the daughter of Ra's al Ghul, and *she has been working with Bane all along*.

So from this point of view,

> she never had to get "free" from Bane.

It would seem that

> she and Bane decided that Lucius could go free, and that she would tag along with Lucius.  To explain to Lucius why he was letting them go, Bane most likely told them that they could do little to harm his siege of the city.

Doing this would be advantageous because

> Lucius would probably seek out or organize some form of resistance, and so if anyone was planning to usurp control of Gotham from Bane, Lucius would know about it or be involved.  By sticking close to Lucius, Miranda would be able to inform Bane, who could then mount a defence.  Basically, a free Lucius was more valuable to them than a captive Lucius.

This is probably exactly what happened,

> given how quickly Bane had found the Special Forces men after they had been brought to Lucius and Miranda.

Comment: Aha, yes excellent point: a little morsel of cheese, to attract any stray rats.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite : Exactly.

Comment: Shouldn't the second spoiler say "...with Bane explaining to them that **Lucius** could do little to affect **their** siege of Gotham"?

Comment: @WadCheber : No, not if the ruse was to be maintained.  Lucius believed that Miranda was a victim, and that lie had to be preserved.

Comment: @Praxis I meant the third spoiler.

Comment: I understood the overall gist of your answer, but misunderstood the wording of  that one bit.  I understood the part about the facade of Miranda's victimhood.

Comment: I thought you meant "Bane told Miranda and the other conspirators that Lucius could go free because Lucius couldn't do anything about the siege".

Comment: @WadCheber: I'm not sure quite what you mean.  In any case, I've reworded it.  Let me know what you think.

Comment: @Praxis - That fixed it.

Comment: @WadCheber : Great.  I agree it's clearer now.  Thanks.  :-)

Comment: No problem.  Happy to be of service.

Comment: I thought the point of letting Lucious go free, was because they knew if Batman (or any one) attempted an offensive, they would try to put the bomb back into the reactor core, thus Lucious was the obvious one to do this and they set a fallback trap in the reactor. As noted when Talia mentioned Lucious showed her how to control the emergency flood.